# can't configure facebook login on django site

Tags: python, django, facebook, heroku

I have a personal Django website hosted by Heroku and I'm trying to configure Facebook login.  I'm using [django-socialregistration](http://django-socialregistration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#) which seems pretty straightforward.  Whether I am looking at my site locally or in production, I keep getting the error:

`Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.`

I expect that error locally, that's fine.  I've read all the other answers on this topic, and all seem to suggest that the problem is in the Site URL setting on the Basic tab.  I've tried:

- sitename.com
- www.sitename.com
- http: //www.sitename.com
- https: //www.sitename.com
- sitename.herokuapp.com

None make any difference.  What am I missing?

EDIT

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'mainsite.views.base', name='base'),
    url(r'^quiz/$', 'quiz.views.quiz', name='quiz'),
    url(r'^results/$', 'quiz.views.results', name='results'),
    url(r'^wedding_party/$', 'mainsite.views.wedding_party',
        name='wedding_party'),
    url(r'^location/$', 'mainsite.views.location', name='location'),
    url(r'^story/$', 'mainsite.views.story', name='story'),
    url(r'^high_scores/$', 'quiz.views.high_scores', name='high_scores'),
    url(r'^photos/$', 'photoalbum.views.photo_album', name='photo_album'),
    url(r'^guestbook/$', 'mainsite.views.guestbook', name='guestbook'),
    url(r'^map/$', 'mainsite.views.map', name='map'),
    url(r'^afterparty/$', 'mainsite.views.afterparty', name='afterparty'),
    url(r'^lodging/$', 'mainsite.views.lodging', name='lodging'),
    url(r'^social/', include('socialregistration.urls',
        namespace='socialregistration')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Facebook settings (one of many configurations I've tried):

Basic > Website > Site URL:  http://www.sitename.com/
Advanced > Valid OAuth redirect URIs:  http://www.sitename.com/ (not sure what this setting is for)

EDIT:

(Canvas settings are new, but did not help)
[image]
[image]
[image]

settings.py

```
try:
    from config import SECRET_KEY, FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY, FACEBOOK_APP_ID
    DEBUG = True
except ImportError:
    DEBUG = False
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
    FACEBOOK_APP_ID = os.environ['FACEBOOK_APP_ID']
    FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY = os.environ['FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY']

# Django settings for wedding project.

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    ('xxxx', 'xxxxx@gmail.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        # 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        # 'NAME': 'django_app_1',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'wedding.db',
        # The rest is not used with sqlite3:
        # 'USER': 'xxxx',
        # 'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
        # 'HOST': 'localhost',
        # 'PORT': '5432',

    }
}
# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

    # Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
if not DEBUG:
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = \
    '/Users/xxxxx/code/wedding/mainsite/static/images/photoalbum/'

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/photos/'

import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'mainsite/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_user_agents.middleware.UserAgentMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'wedding.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wedding.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    'mainsite/templates',
    'quiz/templates',
    'photoalbum/templates',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'mainsite',
    'quiz',
    'photoalbum',
    'django_google_maps',
    'django_user_agents',
    'south',
    'socialregistration',
    'socialregistration.contrib.facebook'
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'socialregistration.contrib.facebook.auth.FacebookAuth',
)
```

EDIT (sites module)
As noted in the comments, the Facebook button was leading to redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fsocial%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback%2F&client_i‌​d=582393191868558.

`example.com` came from the Sites module; I removed it and replaced it with the correct site domain.  Link now goes to:  redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwienerwedding.com%2Fsocial%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback%2F&client_i‌​ d=582393191868558 but it still does not work. (same error)

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your **urls.py**. Can you add that code to your question?

Comment: @mevius Done and done

Answer (score 2):

please show us your facebook app configuration, I think it's the `App Domains` you have miss filled.

You need to create a **facebook app**, use the **+ Add platform**

Try these setteings :

> Basic >
>
> -App Domains : sitename.com
>
> -App on Facebook :
>
> --Canvas URL : http://sitename.com/
>
> --Secure Canvas URL : https://sitename.com/
>
> Advanced >
>
> -Valid OAuth redirect URIs : http://sitename.com/

Comment: Added--let me know if there is other stuff to show.

Comment: a screenshot of your facebook app settings would be far better.

Comment: I did not have the App on Facebook settings; I added them but they did not help.  I added screenshots of my settings pages as requested

Comment: Did you fill the params correctly as shown here? http://django-socialregistration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/contrib/facebook.html   
please show me your settings

Comment: I think I did--it was pretty straight-forward.  Added settings file.  Maybe I made a mistake with how I'm using secret_key and whatnot?  My thought was that it would pull from a config file if I'm developing locally; otherwise from the Heroku environment (assuming I did all that correctly).

Comment: When I went to your site and clicked on connect this is what I found in your url : redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fsocial%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback%2F&client_id=582393191868558   I think this is the error,where the example.com come from?

Comment: Good find--the only thing I can think of is that it's the default value in the Sites framework, which I've never used.  I'll investigate.

Comment: After a lot of work, it now says: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&state=&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwienerwedding.com%2Fsocial%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback%2F&client_id=582393191868558&scope=
But still doesn't work.

Comment: it's better, but please update your question with what have you changed to get this result

Comment: did you fill the app domains in your facebook app settings?

Comment: With something different than what's in the screenshot?  Did I miss something?  The screenshots are still accurate; I have edited to update my removal of the Sites module

Comment: in the screenshots your app domains is empty, you should fill it like this : Basic >

App Domains : sitename.com

Comment: i don't have another idea..try to give the params FACEBOOK_APP_ID and FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY their real value directly instead of using os.environ also fill your namespace in the app settings

Comment: Thanks for trying!  I really appreciate all the effort!

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say anything if we can't see what settings you have in your fb app.

Try this:

```
Settings -> Basic -> Website platform -> Site URL: http://www.sitename.com/
Settings -> Advanced -> Security -> Valid OAuth redirect URIs: http://www.sitename.com/facebook/callback
```

Comment: Added Facebook settings

Comment: Didn't help--does anyone know if the `www` is important?  (I've tried it both ways, just curious.